# Zend 3 Factory Interface

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependencies, factory, zend-framework3

I'm trying to implement Factory for my Controller:

```
class NumberControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface{
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    return new NumberController($container->get(Bar::class));
}

public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $services)
{
    return $this($services, NumberController::class);
}
```

}

I got error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Number\Factory\NumberControllerFactory::__invoke() must be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke(Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\module\Number\src\Number\Factory\NumberControllerFactory.php on line 10
```

I need this, because I want to inject model to controller, because service manager has been removed from controllers in Zend 3.

I used skeleton described in https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/installation.html

In composer.json is:

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
    "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0"
},
```

I don't understand this problem, I read a lot of tutorials, for example:

https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/migration/

coould You help me, please?

I guess that currently this method is compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For injecting model into the controller, you need to create a factory class while configuration in module.config.php as below

```
 'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
    ],
 ],
```

Here AlbumController is the controller class of Album module. After that you need to create a AlbumControllerFactory class inside the module\Album\src\Factory.
In this class you need to write the code below:

```
  namespace Album\Factory;

  use Album\Controller\AlbumController;
  use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
  use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
  use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;


  class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
  {
     public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container,      $requestedName, array $options = null)
     {
      return new AlbumController($container->get(AlbumTable::class));
     }
  }
```

You need to write the below code inside the controller class(AlbumController).

```
   public function __construct(AlbumTable $album) {
     $this->table = $album;
   }
```

This way you can inject the model class into the controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Azhar.

My problem was because when I used:

```
         'factories' => array(
        \Number\Controller\NumberController::class => \Number\Factory\NumberControllerFactory::class
     )
```

it wasn't work, there was 404... I had to use:

```
'Number\Controller\Number' => \Number\Factory\NumberControllerFactory::class
```

in documentation is that I should use full class name ::class.

Does somebody know why it doesn't work?

Comment: You can use the belwo code
'Number\Controller\Number' => Factory\NumberControllerFactory::class
Or 
Controller\NumberController::class => Factory\NumberControllerFactory::class